# Magento + Wordpress Intigration issue

Tags: wordpress, magento

```
<page>
            <rewrite>
                <html>MageWorx_SeoSuite_Block_Page_Html</html>
                <html_head>MageWorx_SeoSuite_Block_Page_Html_Head</html_head>
            </rewrite>
        </page>
```

The above code rewrites the block.
and I am using the following code to create a new header block and then manually adding JS files to header block in my wordpress blog to keep the header and footer same as Magento

```
$layout = Mage::getSingleton('core/layout'); 
$headBlock = $layout->createBlock('page/html_head');
$headBlock->addJs('prototype/prototype.js');
..... and other JS and CSS using the same code
```

But when i use the above code it shoes me error like

```
"Call to a member function getFullActionName() on a non-object in app\code\local\MageWorx\SeoSuite\Block\Page\Html\Head.php on line 53"
```

where the line 53 is

```
        $actionName = $this->getAction()->getFullActionName();
```

The Extension Mageworx_seosuite works fine in Magento without any error , but it gives me error when i try to use it in blog as per the http://www.atwix.com/magento/wordpress-magento/

Can anyone help me what is wrong here.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Magento files are included in Wordpress, there is no actual Magento request running, then no front controller, on which MageWorx extension is usually rightfully relying.

What you could try to do is to force the existence of a dummy front controller, by adding this code after the `$headBlock` creation :

```
if ($headBlock instanceof MageWorx_SeoSuite_Block_Page_Html_Head) {
    $reflectedApp = new ReflectionObject(Mage::app());
    $controllerProperty = $reflectedApp->getProperty('_frontController');
    $controllerProperty->setAccessible(true);
    $controllerProperty->setValue(Mage::app(), new Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front());
    new Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action(Mage::app()->getRequest(), Mage::app()->getResponse());
}
```

But this is not really clean, and may not be sufficient.

Or, you can try to disable the MageWorx rewrite just before creating the block :

```
Mage::app()->getConfig()->setNode('global/blocks/page/rewrite/html_head', '', true);
```

Comment: 2nd option worked but , will it disable the Mageworx rewrite for Magento as well? What if i open  the blog page and magento page at the same time?

Comment: No, as long as you only keep it in your Wordpress file it won't affect your Magento install